# Doing an asynchronous HTTP request - what's the difference between these two?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-waypoints

This is the (default/official) JavaScript code for loading Disqus comments on a web page:

**(CODE #1)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_shortname = 'paulund';

    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

As I see it, the code does the HTTP request asynchronously; but that's not the point.

The thing is, I needed to make some changes to the code so that the comments are loaded only when the user scrolls down to the comments section, as in, lazy loading. **And I've got two working methods to do it.**

**(CODE #2)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#comments').waypoint(function () {

        var disqus_shortname = 'paulund';

        $(function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();

    }, { offset: '100%', triggerOnce: true });
});
```

**(CODE #3)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#comments').waypoint(function () {

        var disqus_shortname = 'paulund';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
            dataType: "script",
            cache: true
        });

    }, { offset: '100%', triggerOnce: true });
});
```

**Questions:**

1. Apart from the obvious fact that I am now doing it with jQuery, is there any difference between what the codes **#1** and **#2**, and **#1** and **#3**, do? Could I possibly be doing something wrong, which I am completely missing?
2. Why don't the codes **#2** and **#3** work when started with `$.noConflict();`? ([After all I found it in the docs as well](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).)

For instance, this doesn't do anything. (But gives an error in the browser console, *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'noConflict' of undefined."*.)

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#comments').waypoint(function () {

        var disqus_shortname = 'paulund';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
            dataType: "script",
            cache: true
        });

    }, { offset: '100%', triggerOnce: true });
});
```

Comment: Nope, no difference. I would use method 3, possibly even shortening down to $.getScript.

Comment: @KevinB If possible please make it an answer. Also, I somehow happened to miss a question earlier. Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: As an aside, your #2 doesn't require the `$({...})()` wrapper around the script element creation code - it shouldn't have the `$` in any case because you don't need a document ready handler after the page has loaded, but you don't need the anonymous function from the #1 version either when the whole thing is contained inside anther function. (The immediately invoked anonymous function in #1 is presumably to keep the `dsq` variable out of the global scope.)

Comment: @nnnnnn So, you are suggesting that I'd do it like this: http://pastebin.com/8LUiHLf5 or like this: http://pastebin.com/6Uq3yKJG. Correct?

Comment: If you want to use #2 then yes, the first of those pastebin samples is what I'm suggesting. If you want to use jQuery then I think it makes more sense to use #3 or your second pastebin sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no difference. I would use method 3. `$.noConflict` should not have any effect if used the way you have it.

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'noConflict' of undefined.* would mean that you've already used `$.noConflict` somewhere else.

Comment: There's not much in the file. Here, please take a look if you can: http://pastebin.com/EJcj0hEb. I am not sure what's causing `$.noConflict` to mess things up.

Comment: Yeah nothing in there should be affected by the `$.noConflict`. `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});` allows you to safely use `$` within `...` without issues.

Comment: I just noticed this error in the console: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'noConflict' of undefined.* And upon searching, I came to know that the solution is to **[declare local jquery variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17319346/1071413)**. So are the docs wrong?

Comment: No, that means you've already used $.noConflict somewhere else.

Comment: **(1)** You are right. I thought WordPress (the CMS I use) loaded the default jQuery file. But I noticed it has this in the end: `jQuery.noConflict();`. That solves the puzzle. Could you please add that to your answer so that I can mark it? **(2)** I don't think using `getScript` is a good idea as it sets the cache setting to false. So, I'd have to do `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });`. Instead I plan to stick with `.ajax` itself. Please let me know if I am wrong, if not, please add a note of this to your answer, so that it's complete with all details for future reference. :) Thank you very much!

Comment: In that case, like I said earlier, (only if you don't mind) please make a note of that as well in your answer. For e.g. like, `getScript` sets the cache setting to false, so you'd have to add `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });` to turn it back on, if you need it. Something like that.

Comment: with the caching in mind i would use what you already have. i'll just remove my sample code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two, both are loading the script asynchronously. You can see for yourself by viewing the rendered script tag in the DOM explorer in your console. If you need it to load synchronously you could utilize the first method and set `dsq.async = false;`. If you are relying on it being loaded before performing some operation, consider adding your dependent operation into a onload callback of the script, that way it will be a non-blocking operation and keep your page loading fast:

```
var disqus_shortname = 'paulund';

(function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.onload = function(){ 
       // dependent code goes here
    }
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```